# Does ModSec block or quarantine an IP address for 1 hour?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, mod-security

I own a business that has a website that creates around 3-4 million pages views a month from about 150k unique users.

This past month one of our partner iOS applications (I believe it is written in React Native) has begun to trigger our hosting security protocols causing the traffic from that application’s WebView (Public IP address also) to be blocked for exactly 1 hour. I assume this is some sort of Mod Sec rule, but my hosting company will give me no details as to why the traffic is being blocked. More interesting is the traffic is not blocked at the start or end of the day but seems to be based on a threshold met. Also interesting is when the block session occurs only iOS 16.4.1 and above devices are blocked. iOS 16.3 and below are always allowed through. No issues on Android or the web version of this application.

I am being told that I need to move to a dedicated server or VPS to handle this sort of traffic (this is not an issue, nor is the money) but I want to be sure this will solve my issue. The hosting company will divulge nothing about their security protocols to the public (cannot say I do not agree with this) so I am a bit in the dark.

I have tired to change the code of the file that the application is linking to which did not work. So I know it has nothing to do with my code, but more to do with the traffic numbers I believe.

Any industry insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

CRS dev-on-duty here. Without more information, this question is very difficult to answer. But as for ModSecurity, I can answer as an OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set (CRS) developer:
ModSecurity has very few rules, only the [recommended rules](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/v3/master/modsecurity.conf-recommended). ModSecurity is mainly the engine.
Most ModSecurity installations use the [OWASP Core Rule Set](https://coreruleset.org/docs/). So I'm trying to answer this question. The OWASP CRS has [basic DoS protection](https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/blob/v3.3.4/rules/REQUEST-912-DOS-PROTECTION.conf). This DoS protection is disabled by default unless the admin enables the rules in [crs-setup.conf](https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/blob/v3.3.4/crs-setup.conf.example#L738-L763).
The fact that only specific user-agents are blocked for one hour speaks against the CRS. The CRS can [block specific user agents](https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/blob/v3.3.4/rules/REQUEST-913-SCANNER-DETECTION.conf) (bots, security scanners, etc.). For example, the CRS can block specific IPs for an hour. However, the standard installation does not combine these functions. Of course it could be configured. So unless you have more information about your provider, it's very hard to tell...
Maybe you could ask your provider to allowlist this specific user-agent, regardless of the blocking mechanism used.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have asked for them to allow that traffic through but they are unwilling to change rules on a shared hosting account...which is understandable but also concerning since they are blocking legitimate traffic...